# How to make a partition on external storage read-only? And revert to normal?

Tags: partitioning, read-only, write-protect, protected

Sometimes, I have to give my external storage someone else. But, I am worry about files and folders which accidentally deleted, moved, changed etc... Therefore, it is enough that data on the disk can be readable. Writing support not desired.

So,

**1)** I want to **make the partition readonly** to prevent deleting and/or writing anything by anyone else.

**2)** When I take back my disk, I will revert it to readable/writeable mode again.

Any utility or method to achieve these goals?

**Edit:** I read about some **hardware-based** solutions and others are valid only at **local PC**. I am searching for **globally valid** and **software-based** solutions.

---

**Solution:**

A [software-based solution](https://superuser.com/a/213015/64376) exists for NTFS volumes. I wrote a PowerShell script to automate explained procedure:

**[PowerShell script to set/clear read-only flag of an NTFS volume](https://gist.github.com/mmdemirbas/5229315)**

Comment: I suggest a backup solution of some type, have your files on 2 or more physical drives, then you can do a compare when the drive is returned to you.

Comment: [The answer](http://superuser.com/a/213015/80304) by Everett from [_How to mount an NTFS partition read-only in Windows?_](http://superuser.com/q/213005/80304) can be what you want.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Yes, it seems like what I want. I will give it a try... Thanks.

Comment: @AlexeyIvanov Thank you, it is exactly what I need. Actually, the solution involves with NTFS only, but it is enough in my case. Please, add your comment as an answer, to be marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Everett's solution](https://superuser.com/a/213015/80304) for NTFS volumes [**How to mount an NTFS partition read-only in Windows?**](https://superuser.com/questions/213005/how-to-mount-an-ntfs-partition-read-only-in-windows)

1. Switch off "automount" by running `mountvol.exe /N`
2. Connect disk to Windows (do not mount the disk)
3. Run `diskpart`

   1. Enter `list volume`
   2. Enter `select volume X`
      (where X is the correct volume number from the previous command)
   3. Enter `att vol set readonly`
   4. Enter `detail vol` and ensure the *read-only* bit is set

Now you can mount the volume and it will be read-only.

To re-enable automatic mounting of new volumes, run `mountvol.exe /E`.

To remove the read-only flag, select the volume in `diskpart` and in step 3.3 enter `att vol clear readonly`.

Comment: Does this readonly flag work if the HD is attached to another workstation?

Comment: @mxmissile I believe it does because it's an attribute written to partition table. On Linux, you can explicitly mount a volume read-only. Anyway, a hardware jumper will give you better protection.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't specified your operating system, so I will assume Windows.

The normal solution is to create a user account, set it as the owner and only one permitted to modify, and giving Everyone the read permission.

This will not work across operating systems (Linux will ignore it), and the administrator on the target machine can always simply take ownership of the disk if he feels like it. So this solution assumes some good will on the part of the recipient.

Otherwise, you will require a hardware solution. Some external disks have write-protect jumpers, such as [Seagate](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=SCSI_Jumper_Settings&vgnextoid=bc71e5cc0783e010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD). You can find such disks in your local or online store.

Comment: I haven't specified operating system, because the solution have to be independent from operating system. It also has to be independent from user account concept. Say that, there is a bit in partition table and if you set it, partition will be read-only. For any user, in any OS.. I'm searching for a solution suchlike.

Comment: Only solution is hardware. See above.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution you can consider is using an encryption wrapper like TrueCrypt. I use this utility to mount my storage wherever I want and you have (password-based) options to decide whether the partition mounted can be modified or read only. Of course it takse one more step and utility to do it, but it's a 2 chicks with one bullet - you also get your info secure.