# Make internal HD read only

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, mount, ntfs, read-only

I would like to make a HD read only to prevent any real changes(except turning off read only). The reason is the hard drive seems to get corrupt for no reason because I never write to it except in rare cases. It is a HD used for storage and all the data is generally read only.

What happens. I believe, is that the SATA cable has problems and when booting up windows either thinks the MFT is bad because the cable gives errors, or at some point wrote data that was corrupt because of the bad cable (or possible SATA controller).

In any case, the drive shouldn't be written to when I'm not writing data... but if I had some way to prevent data from being written when I don't want it to then I could determine if it's the drive or not(since eventually it will become corrupt) and potentially prevent having to copy all the data back to the drive.

The drive's MFT becomes corrupt as far as I can tell, not the files. So, standard file security settings won't work. Is there any way to mark a partition or drive as read only in windows to really prevent writing? (but of course change the flag to write when writing is required)

Comment: You could run attrib +r /s /d but I've never tried it and couldn't promise that it would have a good outcome. You should probably replace the SATA cable if you think that's the problem, maybe even the drive.

Comment: @MarkAllen I've tried changing the cable and the port it is on. attrib won't solve the MFT problem. I've replaced the drive once and the same problem occurs. It is rare but when it happens it is a PITA. The drive always works well with no bad sectors after a format and SMAART returns only CRC errors in the comm(no bad sectors). I would hope surely there is a way to make the OS not write to the HD, which would help me diagnose the problem and potentially solve it.

Comment: A similar question: [How to make read-only a partition on external storage? And revert to normal?](http://superuser.com/q/236786/80304) It has no answer, and I guess there's no universal software-based solution to this.

Comment: Try the other answer then. FWIW I'd never do any of this - this isn't how one troubleshoots a hard drive. (Back up your data so that it no longer matters, then start actually troubleshooting the problem.)

Comment: Always happy to help such a gracious and reasonable person such as yourself. Not sure what I did to anger you, my apologies.

Comment: duplicates: [Is there a way to mount an NTFS partition read-only on Windows without Diskpart?](https://superuser.com/q/1663756/241386), [How can I mount a hard drive as read-only on Windows XP?](https://serverfault.com/q/36385/343888), [How to mount an NTFS partition read-only in Windows?](https://superuser.com/q/213005/241386), [Making an external hard drive "write protected"](https://superuser.com/q/926588/241386)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to mount an NTFS partition read-only in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/213005/how-to-mount-an-ntfs-partition-read-only-in-windows)

Answer (score 6):

First of all, I'd suggest replacing your SATA cable with a new one. It's a robust solution even though you'll make your partition read-only.

[This solution by Everett](https://superuser.com/questions/213005/how-to-mount-an-ntfs-partition-read-only-in-windows/213015#213015) from [another question](https://superuser.com/questions/213005/how-to-mount-an-ntfs-partition-read-only-in-windows) may work for you:

> - Switch off "automount" by running `mountvol.exe /N`
> - Connect disk to Windows (do not mount the disk)
> - Run `diskpart`
>
>   - Enter `list volume`
>   - Enter `select volume X` (where X is the correct volume number from the previous command)
>   - Enter `att vol set readonly`
>   - Enter `detail vol` and ensure the read-only bit is set

Now you can mount the volume, the volume will be read-only.

To re-enable automatic mounting of new volumes use `mountvol.exe /E`.
To remove the read-only flag, select the volume in `diskpart` (use the commands above) and enter `att vol clear readonly`.

Comment: These seems like it should work. I am in the process of copying the data to the drive and will try it when done.