# Is there a way to mount an NTFS partition read-only on Windows without Diskpart?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, mount, ntfs, read-only

I have searched for a while and haven't found anything. Other than using diskpart to set a readonly volume bit. Which is persistent and modifies the partition table, which is not an option for me. And what i've heard turning off auto-mount with mountvol /n doesn't actually work in windows 8.1 either. Is there actually no way to do this without additional hardware?

Comment: Use Linux itself or Windows Subsystem for Linux, and simply mount the NTFS partition read only: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/mount-ntfs-linux

Comment: This sounds like a classical X-Y problem. You have an issue, came up with a solution yourself and now you need help with that solution. If you tell us what you want to accomplish and why you need this (aka, explain the original problem) we may be able to provide a much better solution that is actually doable.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a virtual disk using disk management and attach it read only